# YouTube subscribe link

Tags: hyperlink, youtube, image, subscribe

I am a new coder/web designer and i am trying to add a the youtube logo that when clicked confirm subscription to the users channel

i have a php file with the following coding within...

```
<div id="youtube">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=theansweriscake"><img src="/images/YouTube.png /></a>
</div>
```

this links to confirm subscription and the image directory is correct

however the problem is that whenever i add this into the coding it stuffs everything up!
if you go to any page and right click and go 'inspect element' you will see that the like box for facebook has a box around it which has the room for the youtube picture link
but it doesnt work, as said, when i add it in everything just clumps up together and/or the menu clumps up and goes all weird

Comment: try refreshing it because it wasnt there and when i refreshed it was so try that

Comment: also -- the css for the <div id="youtube">
#youtube {
height: 100px;
width: 220px;
margin-left: 5px;
display: block;
float: left;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had two problems by the looks of things. The first issue was your include filename was wrong and the second was that you missed the closing inverted comma "

This was on the img src= tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `id` to something else - like `<div id="youtube-confirm">`

The `youtube` id might be reserved in FB script and it messes up your and their stuff

Comment: i have changed the facebook like box wrapper from #like to
#facebook-youtube
i have made the box containing the like box long enough to hold the youtube logo as well and this is the coding

Comment: <div id="youtube-facebook">

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FThe-Answer-Is-Cake%2F402458853131124&amp;width=200&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=%23DE92B8&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<div id="subscribe-confirm">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=theansweriscake"><img src="/images/YouTube.png></a>
</div>

</div>

Comment: the css files are 
#youtube-facebook { 
width: 220px;
height: 400px;
margin: 5px 0px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
display: block;
}

#subscribe-confirm {
height: 100px;
width: 220px;
margin-left: 5px;
display: block;
float: left;
}

Comment: Box the youtube link and the facebook box are wrapped in a invisible box (#youtube-facebook) this is 220px x 400px
(facebook is 258px x 200px )
(youtube link has unspecified diameters but the img is 200px x 80px
facebook is wrapped in a box along with the hypothetical youtube link
i will put the youtube link into my php and leave it like that so you can see what happens